# How to add constraints to a collection view cell once the cell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a feature programmatically so that when a user selects a cell in the collection view the app keeps a count of the image selected and adds it as an overlay. I am also wanting to add the video duration to the bottom of the image if the selection is a video. I know my problem is in my constraints. You can see in the image example below that I am trying to add the count to the top left of the collection view cell, but also when the user deselects a cell the count adjusts so for example if the number 2 in the image below was deselected the number 3 would become 2. For the most part I think I have the code working but I cannot get the constraints to work. With the current configuration I am getting an error (see below) but I do not even know where to begin with this problem.

> "Unable to activate constraint with anchors because they have
> no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference
> items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."

**CollectionView:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestCVCell {
            cell.commonInit()

        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestCVCell {
            //Not sure what to put here
        }
    }
```

**Overlay**

```
class CustomAssetCellOverlay: UIView {
    let countSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    lazy var circleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.layer.cornerRadius = self.countSize.width / 2
        view.alpha = 0.4
        return view
    }()
    let countLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return label
    }()
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        addSubview(circleView)
        addSubview(countLabel)

//***** START - UPDATED BASED ON SUGGESTION IN COMMENTS******
countLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//***** END - UPDATED BASED ON SUGGESTION IN COMMENTS******
    countLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    countLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true   
            }
        }
```

**Collection View Cell**

```
var img = UIImageView()
    var overlayView = UIView()
    
    var asset: PHAsset? {
        didSet {}
    }
    
    var isVideo: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            durationLabel.isHidden = !isVideo
        }
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet { overlay.isHidden = !isSelected }
    }
    
    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return view
    }()
    
    var count: Int = 0 {
        didSet { overlay.countLabel.text = "\(count)" }
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval = 0 {
        didSet {
            let hour = Int(duration / 3600)
            let min = Int((duration / 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
            let sec = Int(duration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
            var durationString = hour > 0 ? "\(hour)" : ""
            durationString.append(min > 0 ? "\(min):" : ":")
            durationString.append(String(format: "%02d", sec))
            durationLabel.text = durationString
        }
    }
    
    let overlay: CustomAssetCellOverlay = {
        let view = CustomAssetCellOverlay()
        view.isHidden = true
        return view
    }()
    
    let durationLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 80
        label.backgroundColor = .gray
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        return label
    }()
    
    func commonInit() {      
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.addSubview(overlay)
        imageView.addSubview(durationLabel)
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        

//***** START - UPDATED BASED ON SUGGESTION IN COMMENTS******
    overlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//***** END - UPDATED BASED ON SUGGESTION IN COMMENTS******

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            overlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor),
            overlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor),
            overlay.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leftAnchor),
            overlay.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor),
            
            overlayView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlay.centerXAnchor),
            overlayView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlay.centerYAnchor),
            overlayView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            overlayView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
        ]
        )
    }
//Some other stuff
```

[image: example of image overlay]

Comment: When you are giving constraints using auto layout, you have to add `countLabel. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`,`overlay. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`,`overlayView. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` which tells iOS not to create autoLayout constraints automatically and also check your contraints

Comment: Kishan I updated my code based on your suggestions (see the updated post) but I am still seeing the same issue. Any other thoughts?